# Create new product from custom module

Tags: magento

Im making a module to import products from another system, but I cant find a way to actually save the product. This is what i have tried:

```
$new_product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$productInfoData['sku'] = 'mySKU';
$productInfoData['price'] = '10';
$productInfoData['name'] = 'The name';
$productInfoData['status'] = 1;

// then set product's general info to update
$new_product->setData($productInfoData);

// call save() method to save your product with updated data
$new_product->save();
```

But this does not seem to work :(

Could anybody help me on the right track?

BR/Sune

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What doesn't work?

Comment: You're way short on information to save the product. Do you get a specific error here?

Comment: What is the output when you call $new_product->getId() after the call to save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
                    $new_product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

                $new_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
                $new_product->setSku('lu-'.$product['sku']);
                $new_product->setPrice((($product['price'])*$e_rate));
                $new_product->setCategoryIds(array(1152));
                $new_product->setAttributeSetId(4); 
                $new_product->setVisibility(1);             
                $new_product->setType('Simple Product');
                $new_product->setName($product['name']);
                $new_product->setDescription('');
                $new_product->setShortDescription('');
                $new_product->setStatus(2); 
                $new_product->setTaxClassId(2);
                $new_product->setWeight(0);             
                $new_product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));                   


                // call save() method to save your product with updated data
                $new_product->save();
```

where $product is an array with new product information.

This works just perfect!